# Smoother animation in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif

I created a `.gif` animation in Photoshop, but the motion seems very "jumpy" instead of smooth. It's just some text that rises. What can I do to make it a smooth move?

Comment: Can you post your `.gif` file as an example?

Comment: More importantly then the gif, post a screenshot of Photoshop with the frame/animation panel showing. Sounds like you've got an FPS issue.

Comment: I'd love to, but I don't see how to post the gif or the screenshot to this thread?

Comment: I guess there's that restriction for new users. Just host it somewhere like imgur, dropbox, etc... And post the url here. Someone will edit your answer to include the image. Just make sure it's not adult content or somehow offensive. -- Chances are that After Effects would be better for what you are doing. Even if you are not doing anything like this http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31207/how-to-create-animated-gifs-of-prototype-mockups-like-the-ones-on-dribbble/31302#31302 that answer gives a pretty good insight on basic stuff you need to know to animate in AE.

Comment: Add more transitional frames? Hard to know without seeing the animation panel!

Answer (score 3):

Most computer displays are 60hz (60 frames per second). The magic numbers you need for the Frame Delay are:

- 2 frames at 60hz = 0.0333333333th of a second = 0.03s frame delay.
- 3 frames at 60hz = 0.0666666667th of a second = 0.06s frame delay.

Most of the time, a 0.03 or 0.06 second frame delay is what you’ll be after.

[image: Photoshop Frame Delay for animation]

Answer (score 0):

It is because of minimum number of frames. If you want to avoid jumping of frames use Flash professional. Or increase the number of frames in Photoshop