# Rotate an object smoothly in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, animate

i am currently using Photoshop CS6 and there is no "create video animation" option in timeline tab.

I have only one option to create animation via "create frame animation".

I want to rotate a horoscope wheel to make a gif format file.

Please help me, how to rotate smoothly (without any jerk)  via frame by frame animation in short time/ short method.

Comment: Or how to find "create video animation" option in Windows(not Mac)  version

Comment: please help me its urgent

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-frame-animations.html or http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop-premiere-elements.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Smoother animation in Photoshop?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/33800/smoother-animation-in-photoshop)

Comment: but i don't want to create 360 layers and frames to rotate this... it is so much irritating me. :(

Comment: Use a proper animation program such as Adobe Flash then which should be included in your subscription to Adobe Creative Cloud.

Comment: I am a student and i dont have CC version of flash

Comment: I have only a portable version of photoshop cs6

Comment: Well my friend, you will have to learn the hard way by creating layers and rotating each layer by 5 or 10 degrees to create the frame by frame animation.

Comment: @SachinGoyal as a student its less than $200 to get the entire Creative Cloud suite for the year. It's only $20 to just get Flash for the month if you don't plan on doing animations regularly. This isn't exactly a huge financial burden like it used to be.

Comment: @Ryan, the original poster is asking to do it with Photoshop. Also Photoshop has tools dedicated to make animated GIFs. I don't understand why are Adobe subscription prices relevant.

Comment: @chimos because if you read the other comments the person states they do not want to do a layer by layer animation so I was suggesting using a better tool.

Comment: Ok it's true, sorry. Now I realize my answer is not satisfactory for the OP. Would be good to make the question more concise. The OP doesn't want to "rotate", but "animate something that rotates", and with an interpolation instead of frame by frame. My suggestion "Create a smooth animation with two keyframes in Photoshop CS6".

Comment: hey, sorry for the late rply. @chimos and @ ryan thanks for your comments but i think there is an installation problem in my software. i know very well how to animate an object in photoshop, but i am surprise because of there is only frame by frame animation in my photoshop. i also know the hard way (by creating layers and rote 5-8 degre) to rotate but it really tooo hard to keep petitions. :( 

thats why i am asking.

Comment: now look what i have done.... http://softwebstudioz.com/websites/astrothakur/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To find the right tool panel in Photoshop:**
For *Photoshop CS5* and lower, access the animation window by opening “Window” + “Animation.” Likewise, click “Window” + “Timeline” in *Photoshop CS6* and Photoshop CC to access the Timeline window. For *Photoshop CC*, click the drop-down menu in the middle of the Timeline window and select “Create Frame Animation.”

**Then**, one method would be having each frame of your animation in one separate layer. It means that, in your case, you should have the same object in all layers, but with different angle rotations applied to each of them.

**To duplicate a layer:**
Right click on the layer to see context menu, click on "Duplicate Layer".

**To rotate an object:**
With Photoshop you can select any object (you should select the right layer where the object is), right click on the object to see context menu, select "Transform" and you will be able to rotate the object manually (by dragging one corner) or writing the exact angle in the angle input on the top bar (it appears after you click on "transform").

In the Photoshop’s sequencing tool panel we activated before, click on small, right-facing arrow in the upper-right hand corner, and then select “Make Frames From Layers.”

**The smoothness** of the animation depends on how much frames you have and how fast do you show them. If you use 24 fps (Frames Per Second) or a higher value, no jumps between frames will be noticed by the viewer.

More info about animation smoothness: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/learning_guide/animation/part02.html

Source and tutorial about animated gifs with Photoshop: [http://www.digitaltrends.com/social-media/how-to-make-an-animated-gif](http://www.digitaltrends.com/social-media/how-to-make-an-animated-gif/)