# How do I create a mockup of an app on desktop and iphone?

Tags: mockup

I don't know how to describe exactly what I'm looking for, but I've seen a service which allows me to take a mockup or illustration and put it realistically in pre-made images of a Mac and iPhone.

But I can't recall where I saw it or how to do it.  I don't want to take, for example, a flat image and then figure out how to fit it and rotate it into a stock Mac laptop image.

I am pretty sure I saw an app which did this, but I can't remember it, or perhaps there's an easier way to do this.

Comment: Somewhat related [How to create animated GIFs of prototype mockups, like the ones on Dribbble?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/31207/2332)

Comment: I feel like this has been asked like 2-3 times a week, recently.

Comment: relevant and an attempt at a blanket answer: [How to mockup a logo in a realistic environment?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113783/how-to-mockup-a-logo-in-a-realistic-environment)

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to achieve this.

1. Search google and type "psd mockups iphone" , "psd mockups ipad", etc.
2. Explore some designers showcase like dribbble, behance, etc and look for free mockups.
3. Follow designers that create mockups on twitter and they will tweet when they release a new mockup.
4. Use some online tools like https://placeit.net/ .

Comment: placeit was the application I was looking for