# Trying to reduce the area a layer can bee seen in After effects

Tags: layers, animation, interface-design, adobe-after-effects

I'm creating a UI animation for a phone. I've got it so the menu transitions slowly moves in from the side. However as you can see the menu can be seen coming in from outside of the screen like the image below.

How can I make it so the layer can only be seen within the green rectangle, so I can keep the same transition, but you can only see it occur within the phones screen?

[image]

Comment: You could mask it, but I would probably make a new comp with the dimensions of the green area and then drag it to the main comp as a footage. On a somewhat unrelated note, maybe this could be useful to you: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31207/how-to-create-animated-gifs-of-prototype-mockups-like-the-ones-on-dribbble/31302#31302

Comment: @Joonas It worked thanks :) Not sure if you want to leave it as an actual answer so I can give you some points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a new comp <kbd>Cmd+N</kbd> with the screen dimensions, and in the project panel, drag that new comp into your main comp. Then you can make the UI animations within that new comp and they will be updated to your main comp. The new comp size will work sort of like mask in this case.

If you've already created/animated the layers in your main comp, you can select them and choose [`Layer > Pre-compose…`](http://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/precomposing-nesting-pre-rendering.html) from the top menu, and the layers you selected will be put into their own comp. Then you can edit the settings of that comp to match the screen size.