# Pixelated images and smart objects in Adobe CC suite

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, website-design, smartobject, pixelation

I have been using Adobe softwares for a couple of years now and I never had this issue before. Every time I save for web (png), or even pasting smart objects from illustrator to photoshop I get a really low res, pixelated image. I tried everything: Resolution is at 300 dpi, anti alias is turned on. Nothing works and it's driving me crazy. I checked all the adobe forums and no one has a solution. I do have a macbook pro retina display but that should have nothing to do with it. The strangest thing is: it used to work a couple of months ago perfectly. Can someone please tell what could be causing this issue? Thank you

[image]

Comment: By "pixelated" are you referring to a few dark speck on the light background? I was expecting to see pixel blocks, ragged edges which do not show on my screen. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't see the issue that you describe. For this size, it doesn't look abnormally blurry or pixelated to me.  What is see: **1.** The shadow in the middle is kind of cut off. **2.** The edge of each of those lighter, tall trees is a bit sharp, but not really a big deal. **3.** The text looks a bit garbled, but also normal for this size. You could try to fix that a little by changing  anti-aliasing to `Crisp` and/or using a different font. --- Everything I noticed seems to be unrelated to exporting.

Comment: @Joonas  This might not look as bad on other devices. What device are you using? I know it's not too bad but it's still not as crisp and clear as I would have liked it. I had a similar issue with the logo which was awful and the only way to sort it, was to have someone else on other laptop to save the file for me. There is definitely an issue here with Adobe CC.  I will try to post more examples...

Comment: @Joonas another thing: I was following this tutorial

Comment: @Joonas another thing: I was following this tutorial (http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31207/how-to-create-animated-gifs-of-prototype-mockups-like-the-ones-on-dribbble) to upload a GIF to my website. Long story short: turns out I can't upload GIF's so I uploaded a video instead done in AE using the technique described here and again it turned out blurry (check it here: https://vimeo.com/152917562). I saved it in various formats but same thing it's not crisp and clear. Problem is no matter how I save the files..they never turn out crisp as in this tutorial...

Comment: I don't know what so say. Aside from the text, I don't really see much anything wrong with the picture in the question on a desktop browser. The video does look a bit like it's upsized or just blurry. Without seeing when it turns blurry like that, It's difficult to guess anything. There could be something fishy there, as the tablet edges look pretty crisp. It's just the screen that is blurry.

Comment: So it starts to look blurry after export, not before it?

Comment: @Joonas Hey, thanks for taking a look. With the video it turns blurry once I skew it and no matter how I export it's still the same thing. With the posters, although they are smart objects and so they look crisp and clear..once I resize them they get pixelated (not a lot). On the other hand, with the logo, unfortunately I don't have an example to show you now..will post some tomorrow, but that I assure you it looked crisp in illustrator, once exported for web was horrible. Nothing worked! I know I am not crazy, it happened to others as well..but no one found the solution..

Comment: @joonas This issue has been addressed several times on adobe forums and someone addressed it here as well but got no answers, except the usual ones: resolution, anti aliasing, align to pixel and all that. (http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/56237/illustrator-files-appear-pixelated-when-its-saved-to-web)

Comment: If you can make example files that have the same issues, I could take a look at them an see what could be causing it. You could link them through dropbox or something.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.  Apparently, there is a check box "Anti-alias" at the top that has to be checked.  Never had to do this before in any previous versions of Photoshop.  But it fixed it.

[image: The Anti-alias check box]

This check box appears right after you paste the object into Photoshop, and the lasso is still around the object. Look for the bar with the information above, the "anti-alias" box is right there.