# Tool for creating animated gifs of UIs

Tags: tools, gif, prototyping

I recently read this article (https://uxdesign.cc/design-better-data-tables-4ecc99d23356) about data tables. The article contains a bunch of uses for data tables. To communicate the ideas, the author is using some animated gifs if the data tables.

My question is, does anyone know what tool was used to create those animated designs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create animated GIFs of prototype mockups, like the ones on Dribbble?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31207/how-to-create-animated-gifs-of-prototype-mockups-like-the-ones-on-dribbble) -- Although, those particular gifs could just be a [screen recording converted to an animation](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/790/how-to-embed-screen-capture-videos-as-animated-gifs-in-answers)

Comment: https://www.invisionapp.com/blog/7-tips-for-designing-awesome-gifs/ is an excellent resource for those not wanting to dive all the way into Premier.

Comment: Ask the author, to be totally hpnest you could do those in anything even notepad

Answer (score 0):

You can use adobe premiere to create any type of gif or video or adobe animate if you want something more like drawings, for example to make animations for 2d cartoons.
Adobe premiere is more general and allows you to edit frame by frame, add animations on some objects, edit sounds; you can use it to create videos or gifs

Comment: I think Premiere would not be the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the article you linked, it seems you are interested in finding the best way to prototype.

You've got a couple of choices here and it's something worth following as there are constantly new tools being developed to help with the prototyping stage.

I agree that though the gifs could be created in Premier, it's not the ideal option as there are more efficient ways to accomplish this.

From my experience, the [Invision app](https://www.invisionapp.com/) is the common solution. It can be coupled with your Photoshop or Sketch files to enable prototyping. If Sketch is your preferred tool just this week Invision has announced [prototyping within Sketch](https://www.invisionapp.com/blog/prototyping-in-sketch/) which you may find useful.

That said, [Adobe XD](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/experience-design.html?sdid=19SCDRPP&mv=search&s_kwcid=AL!3085!3!183347083847!e!!g!!adobe%20xd&ef_id=WSAnUwAABZg47l7n:20170520112758:s) is now available on both Windows and Mac for free download (it's in a powerful Beta state (detailed [here](https://medium.com/thinking-design/making-adobe-xd-redefining-beta-1a8383601f7d) by their Director for Engineering, Vincent Hardy) and is updated monthly). This will give you the opportunity, to build, prototype and provide the relevant specs for your designs all in one spot.

Hope this helps!