# Video in photoshop mockup

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-after-effects, mockup, adobe-xd

I just created a design in Adobe XD and then I exported it to After Effects and made some animations. I downloaded a Photoshop mockup for iPhone X and now I want to use that video created in After Effects on the ps mockup. I tried creating a timeline in ps but the process it's very slow and buggy. Is there any way to use my video on that mockup? 
Thank you!

Comment: This answer seems related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31207/how-to-create-animated-gifs-of-prototype-mockups-like-the-ones-on-dribbble/31302#31302 - It contains some outdated and false information, but for the most part it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use After Effects to put them together, not Photoshop.

Import the mockup file (`.psd`) into your Ae project and place the animation inside the mockup frame.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in ps my footage goes in a smart object and if I'm importing the ps comp into ae the smart object is just an image, not another composition where I should put my video.

Comment: You can unsmart object it and *extract* a `.png` of the phone and make that into a still layer with the animation inside the phone frame.

Comment: I actually just found a way without having to deal with the smart layer in ps. I used corner pin effect and adjusted the video comp to fit the iphone screen